Animating an object entering, pausing and then exiting a bottle
I'm new to animation and feel like I may have taken on more than I can handle. In this animation, I have an object that enters a bottle and gets stuck inside (with the cap of the bottle closed). Then, the cap of the bottle opens, and the object comes out. So far, I've managed to animate the object entering the bottle with the cap closed.
However, I want the object to pause while it is stuck in the bottle, and then, once the cap reopens, I want the object to resume and exit the bottle.

The orange outline is of the object and at this scene, the cap has reopened for the object to exit.
I'm really struggling with getting the object to exit. Do I expand the existing path or can I create a new path (can an object be linked to multiple paths?) ?
I'm also getting slightly confused - When I add a key frame, do I add it to the object, the curve or both?
Temporarily adding the blend file for clarity. I want the object to leave at 148th or so frame.
Edit:


On the Follow Path constraint there is an Influence value which can be animated. So, yes you can use multiple paths. First you have the influence at 1 for the first path, then you switch it to 0 and for the second path the other way round from 0 to 1. But notice that if you would have the Influence at 0 for both, the object does not stay on any of the curves, it moves to its original place. So you have to combine them in a way that the end point of one curve is the starting point of the other or at least that you get a transition that does not reset the object in a weird way.

maybe the simplest would be extend your curve but you'll need to change the Evaluation Time because extruding your curve will change the position of the bee object on the curve. Also you'll need to duplicate a keyframe so that it stops before leaving at frame 150:

Result:


I was able to get the object to pause and exit. I duplicated the keyframe from 90 to 140 which is where it pauses and at 150th frame, I set my evaluation time to 85.8 so that it exits. However, the extruding still made my object upside down. Should I try not to extrude at all? Adding a screenshot in the edit. Thank you for all your helpful responses!

could you please share your file? Generally for this kind of animation give a Follow Path constraint to the object then keyframe the Evaluation Time of the curve

Also maybe for your curve choose Twist Method > Z-Up

thank you, i added the blend file under edit 2. I could be missing out something very simple.
Thank you, i will check out twist method!

to reorientate your object, either change the tilt of the curve vertices (Ctrl T or in the N panel > Item > Transform > Tilt), or keyframe the local X axis of the object (R to rotate then double X to rotate on its axis, then i to keyframe)
